# Need help to improve execution time for face detection in OpenCV 2.4.0

Tags: android, c, opencv

I'm using the `cvHaarDetectObjects` C function to detect faces in my Android application, but the execution time is not fast enough to process a certain number of video frames per second. So, I'm thinking of commenting out code that is unnecessary for me, e.g. I've noticed a lot of branching conditions for the flags and memory allocation statements that can be commented out. The same thing can be done for the functions that are called from `cvHaarDetectObjects`.

Has anyone tried doing this sort of optimization before? Any help is much appreciated.

Code:

```
cascadeFile1 = (CvHaarClassifierCascade *) cvLoad(cascadeFace,0,0,0);
CvSeq *face = cvHaarDetectObjects(img1, cascadeFile1, storage,1.1, 3,CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING,cvSize(0,0));
```

Comment: Need to see your code, to help you optimize it.

Comment: @alex The code I use is: cascadeFile1 = (CvHaarClassifierCascade *) cvLoad(cascadeFace,0,0,0); CvSeq *face = cvHaarDetectObjects(img1, cascadeFile1, storage,1.1, 3,CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING,cvSize(0,0));

Comment: But,can this code be optimised? I thought that there's nothing that can be done with the code in the previous comment. That's why I thought of optimising the opencv source code by commenting out functionality that I don't need. I think the source code should be available online I'll provide you with the link if I can find it.

Comment: [This](http://code.opencv.org/svn/opencv/trunk/opencv/modules/objdetect/src/haar.cpp) is the official code repository. cvHaarDetectObjectsForROC is the function I'm trying to get to run faster.

Answer (score 0):

As a first step you should try to tune the input parameters, as these have a big impact on the performance of the classifier.

You could try to:

1. reduce the source image resolution to a reasonable value
2. increase the `scaleFactor` parameter by small amounts (e.g `0.1` steps)
3. depending on your resolution, camera field of view and distance of faces, define values for the `min_size` and `max_size` parameters. This can dramatically influence the number of operations the algorithm needs to perform.

Second you could post your actual parameters and your profiling results and people around here can surely give some more hints on what to improve.

As a side note: I don't think that commenting out branching conditions will make a noticeable difference in speed if you want to leave the algorithm functioning.

Comment: I've already tuned and played around with the input parameters. What I've done is:  1. Reduced the image resolution to 176*144  2. I find the face detection is most accurate when the scaling is at 10%, so I'm not very keen to change this parameter  3. Since the resolution of my image is 176*144 and input video feed is from the frontal camera of a phone, I've decided to let the max_size parameter be (0,0) so that faces detection works even when the camera is held too close to the face. As for the min_size, I will change that to around a fifth of the image resolution.